# Access Virtual Box from all networks

Tags: android, virtualbox

Hi I have loaded my Android (`iso image`) in the `virtual box` and trying to access it from all the networks. I made it bridged network and able to access from all  the machines having series-`xx.xx.xx.y` but not from `xx.xx.tt.s`

Please advice me to make my `virtual box` to be accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Can you write down the XX? It's kinda important, because it seems that it's some problem with the netmask.

If the first address is for example, `192.168.1.32` with netmask `255.255.255.0 (24)` it won't be accessible by hosts in `192.168.2.x`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork